# Saving Dead letter messages in file system/database

Tags: apache-camel, mq, spring-camel

I am new in Camel world.
Basically i am looking a way to store camel dead letter message in file/RDBMS system.

```
<camelContext trace="true" id="mybeanId" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" autoStartup="true" errorHandlerRef="myErrorHandler">

        <errorHandler id="myErrorHandler" type="DeadLetterChannel" deadLetterUri="file:errors" >              
            <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="-1" redeliveryDelay="5000"/>
        </errorHandler>
<!-- route details -->
</camelContext>
```

with the configuration i can see when message received from MQ and it send to route 1 for example and somehow route1 is failed to process.

in that case i can see log:
JmsConsumer[Uploader]) [-] [] Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:on ExchangeId: ). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: cause
That means my myErrorHandler is working.

Now when i restarted my JVM i can see this unprocessed message is lost. So looking for way where i can store this message file system or database so when we restarted JVM and consumer is up we will able to process this message.

I am referring : https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/eips/dead-letter-channel.html

**UPDATE:**
Also tried with :

```
<errorHandler id="myErrorHandler" type="DeadLetterChannel" deadLetterUri="file:C:\Users\Temp?fileName=MyFile.txt" useOriginalBody ="true">              
            <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="-1" redeliveryDelay="5000"/>
        </errorHandler>
```

But no luck.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you considered using a `direct` route as the `deadLetterUri` value, and add some `log` to see if the dead letter channel is sending it to the route?

You might need to build a processor to handle the message body to send it exactly to where you want it end up.

Otherwise, [onPrepareFailure](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/eips/dead-letter-channel.html#_calling_a_processor_before_sending_a_message_to_the_dead_letter_queue_using_onpreparefailure) is a good way to intercept dead letter channel to send it to another endpoint on top of the nominated jms dead letter queue.